# Filtering powershell output with search pattern beginning with some-pattern and ending with other-pattern

Tags: powershell

I was inspired by the bash command line in which `sed` outputs the search pattern beginning with "-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-" and ending with "-END CERTIFICATE-"

```
openssl s_client -connect www.domain.com:443 -showcerts | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
```

just how do I get the filter so that it works in powershell, probably with `Select-String`?

Here is the output of the bash command:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -showcerts | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIJVzCCCD+gAwIBAgIRANFJW61SRurECAAAAABTHOIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
...cut...
jPCWTiAulvBLJJQ9nmggAgaEg7/9bs6da47V5awlyEAKzzmHGAmcNpX71Q==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIESjCCAzKgAwIBAgINAeO0mqGNiqmBJWlQuDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBMMSAw
...cut...
USpxu6x6td0V7SvJCCosirSmIatj/9dSSVDQibet8q/7UK4v4ZUN80atnZz1yg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

a total of 77 lines

Comment: Yes, `Select-String` would be a good start. Otherwise, you can also use `-match`.

Comment: I use Select-String -Context 0,27 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE' - but if the certificate is longer then 27 lines the output will be cut off. I looking for a filter in which from a pattern until a pattern, everything between 1st pattern and 2nd pattern should be printed out.

Comment: Please show us a sanitized example of the output to parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing builtin quite as concise as `sed`, but I often find the `switch` statement useful for parsing multi-line output with regex line-by-line:

```
# flag to keep track of whether we're between BEGIN/END
$inCert = $false

# suppress stderr output from openssl, assign all output from switch to `$certs`
$certs = switch -Regex ("`n`n"|openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -showcerts 2>$null){
  '-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-' {
    # alright, we encountered a BEGIN line, prepare to consume following lines as a cert
    $partialCert = @()
    $inCert = $true
  }
  '-END CERTIFICATE-' {
    # reach END, output the current certificate
    $inCert = $false
    $partialCert -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
  }
  default {
    # ignore anything as long as we're not in between BEGIN/END
    if($inCert){
      $partialCert += $_
    }
  }
}

# $certs now contain the base64-encoded certificates
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a pitty you didn't show us an example of the output you received from the `showcerts` command, but I suppose it will look something like this:

```
CONNECTED(00000002)
--snip--
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = www.openssl.org
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFVTCCBD2gAwIBAgISAwk9QUiwVmoQAtcCLKybaK7yMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
...
mQBom1EISBOiNyu5koR6iRZcXsn6x/4kwA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEkjCCA3qgAwIBAgIQCgFBQgAAAVOFc2oLheynCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/
...
KOqkqm57TH2H3eDJAkSnh6/DNFu0Qg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
...
```

If you capture that in a variable, say `$rawCerts` you can make use of `-split`, `-match` and `-replace` to get an array of the actual base64 encoded certificates like below:

```
$certs = $rawCerts -split '(?sm)-BEGIN CERTIFICATE[-\r\n]+' |             # split into textblocks
         Where-Object {$_ -match '-END CERTIFICATE-'} |                   # take only the blocks that contain '-END CERTIFICATE-'
         ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '(?sm)[\r\n-]+END CERTIFICATE.*' }  # remove everything after and including '-END CERTIFICATE-'
```

<sup>P.S> `(?sm)` in the regex means Dot matches newline (s) and Characters ^ and $ match at line breaks (m)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

this is the raw output without `sed`

```
CONNECTED(00000178)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = *.google.com
   i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIJVzCCCD+gAwIBAgIRANFJW61SRurECAAAAABTHOIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
...<cut>...
jPCWTiAulvBLJJQ9nmggAgaEg7/9bs6da47V5awlyEAKzzmHGAmcNpX71Q==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
   i:OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIESjCCAzKgAwIBAgINAeO0mqGNiqmBJWlQuDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBMMSAw
...<cut>...
USpxu6x6td0V7SvJCCosirSmIatj/9dSSVDQibet8q/7UK4v4ZUN80atnZz1yg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = *.google.com

issuer=C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: ECDSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3807 bytes and written 392 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
verify return:1
```